# Using different relay for refrigerator’s card

Tags: refrigerator, relay

My refrigerator’s electonic card has a panasonic Js1f-b-12v-f relay on it. I need to change it but I only can find panasonic Js1-b-12v-f on the market. When I check the datasheet of both, I saw a little difference between them. Is it ok replacing the old one with this new one?

Comment: What was the little difference?

Comment: This would probably be better suited at [electronics.se]. They're more up on actual electronic components and could - given the specs are provided - tell you whether the proposed replacement is within the operational realm of the original.

Comment: @crip659 The "f" part stands for "flux-resistance", the nil one stands for "sealed" or "fully sealed".

Comment: @FreeMan Electrical Engineering does not do repair type questions.

Comment: No, @SolarMike, but they do support "is this part a suitable replacement for that part" questions (at least they appear to).

Comment: @FreeMan They closed the question :D btw I still couldn't get an answer :/

Comment: You asked at [electronics.se] and they closed it? Under what account? What reason did they give to close?

Comment: @FreeMan one-word: "out-of-topic"

Comment: In the future don't watch your question get closed and then open another question.  Hit "Flag"..."mod intervention" and key in "move to (stack you want to move the question to".  Easy and reduces system clutter.

Comment: yes, that's fine. the important relay datasheet lines to match up are coil resistance (aka drive voltage), contact current/voltage rating, and footprint.